# How to Debug in Eclipse step by step?

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I am using Eclipse to run my java files. I want to trace the running of my jave program, step by step WITHOUT using the debugger breakpoints. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use F5 and F6 and F7, i dont remember correctly right now, you can play with it.

F6 - will take you through the flow of execution.

F7 - will directly take you to the next break point.